# "atheistic scientist" vs "atheist scientist"

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives, suffixes, rules

I know that it's "atheist scientist" but "atheistic regime", "atheist YouTuber" but "atheistic channel" in common use but I can't find out why. When do we use "atheistic" and when "atheist" and why?

Example:

1. Dawkins is one of the ____ scientists, who are organizing to fight organized religion and dogma.
2. XYZ is a pretty good ______ youtuber.
3. Communist regimes are usually _____.

Edit: Comment to "English Student". It's too long so I added here instead as further thought:

My problem with this is I have never heard "atheistic scientist".  I have heard "atheist regime" or  "atheist channel".

So it seems it is considered all right to use "atheist" or "atheistic" in cases where noun being modified is abstract and the implication is that atheism is part and parcel of the said abstract noun.

But "Noun-as-Adjective" form is always used when talking about a person and the implication is that this person just happens to be an atheist.

This can't be a coincidence. There has to be some underlying rule. Maybe the semantic difference I explained IS THE RULE or we're missing something.

Answer (score 1):

The generic situation here is [nouns being used as adjectives](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm). This is now accepted by most users of English and atheistic/atheist is not a special case. Although ***atheistic*** might be the technically correct adjectival form, it can be replaced everywhere by the [adjectival noun](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) 'atheist' to reflect modern and current usage, as in your examples:

> Dawkins is one of the *atheist* scientists (...)
>
> XYZ is a pretty good *atheist* youtuber.
>
> Communist regimes are usually *atheist*.

You can equally replace 'atheist' with 'atheistic' in any of those sentences. Other examples are modernistic/modernist, minimalistic/minimalist and nihilistic/nihilist.

It is no coincidence here that words like atheist, minimalist, modernist and nihilist (also optimist and feminist) are nouns for people or organizations following particular philosophies, ideologies, aesthetic movements or attitudes to life. The -ic adjectival form of many such nouns is no longer mandatory and the noun frequently becomes its own adjective in current usage:

> Modernistic trends in architecture have redefined Arab cityscapes.
>
> *Modernist* architecture aims to be functional and eco-friendly.
>
> The minimalistic approach to literature eschews rhetorical flourishes.
>
> His *minimalist* approach profoundly influenced modern art.
>
> Sorry, I think that is a [nihilist attitude](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22nihilist+attitude%22&client) [but *nihilistic* would be [more commonly used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nihilistic+attitude%2C+nihilist+attitude&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnihilistic%20attitude%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnihilist%20attitude%3B%2Cc0) here].

---

*"My problem with this is I have never heard "atheistic scientist"* __ I checked it out because OP's edit is very specific, and found that according to Google Ngrams "atheistic scientist" is used much more frequently than "atheist scientist", see [Ngrams comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=atheistic+scientist%2Catheist+scientist&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Catheistic%20scientist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Catheist%20scientist%3B%2Cc0).

However, "atheist state" became more popular than "atheistic state" in the last 20 years, according to [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=atheistic+state%2Catheist+state&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Catheistic%20state%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Catheist%20state%3B%2Cc0) while "atheistic regime" and "atheist regime" are found used rather [evenly](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=atheistic+regime%2C+atheist+regime&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Catheistic%20regime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Catheist%20regime%3B%2Cc0) by frequency from the 1920's to the present day (there was no atheistic regime in history and therefore no recorded use of the term before the Bolsheviks consolidated power following the Russian Revolution and the Russian Civil War.)

In fact "atheist leader" has been more [popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=atheistic+leader%2Catheist+leader&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Catheistic%20leader%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Catheist%20leader%3B%2Cc0) than "atheistic leader" since 1935, which begins to support OP's hypothesis, but "atheist scientist" does not help his case. My point is that **Ngrams reveal no clear pattern** of preferring 'atheistic' for words like 'regime' and 'state' while preferring 'atheist' for words like 'scientist' or 'leader'. That seems to suggest that ***"atheist" may indeed nowadays be preferred as adjective in certain situations, possibly for stylistic reasons, but it's unlikely there's a "rule" that OP is looking for***, and the 4 Ngrams taken together support my idea that though "atheistic" is the technically correct adjective, the noun "atheist" is also well accepted as adjective in current usage:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Finally, regarding OP's suggestion in question and [comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/434268/atheistic-scientist-vs-atheist-scientist/434288#comment1045318_434288) that maybe "atheistic scientist" is used when atheism is integral to the being a scientist, and "atheist scientist" is used when the person happens to be a scientist *and also* an atheist:

in practice, when either form is used as a direct adjective preceding the noun as in "atheistic scientist" or "atheist scientist" it's very unlikely to be understood that the scientist *just happens to be* atheist. Adjectives are almost always considered significant descriptors in modern usage. If we actually want to describe a scientist who also happens to be atheist, we are much more likely to say

> "he is a scientist, and atheist"

or

> "that scientist is an atheist"

thus avoiding tightly binding "atheist" & "scientist" in an explicit adjective-noun conjunction when they are only loosely related here.That is just like saying

> that doctor is a violinist

to indicate that

> that doctor is ***also a*** violinist

whereas if you were to say "violinist doctor", some important relationship would be assumed between being "violinist" and "doctor", at least in that particular case.

---

In conclusion: when both forms are acceptable it becomes a matter of style!

Comment: I don't think that's quite right. I made an edit to clarify.

Comment: *"My problem with this is I have never heard "atheistic scientist"* __ I checked because your edit is very specific, and found that according to google ngrams "atheistic scientist" is used much more frequently than "atheist scientist" @Lalit Jindal, see https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=atheistic+scientist%2Catheist+scientist&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Catheistic%20scientist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Catheist%20scientist%3B%2Cc0 Supports my point that "atheistic" is the technically correct adjective but "atheist" is also being accepted now.

Comment: I have tried to make the images smaller as described here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/please-do-something-to-encourage-people-to-scale-down-their-giant-heavyweight-ph?noredirect=1&lq=1 but it still seems pretty similar to the previous size.

Comment: Thanks @sumelic. They look somewhat smaller now but the page scales them up anyway, I think.

Comment: Well, they could be made even smaller by editing the "l" at the end of the links to "m" or "s", but that seemed to make it too difficult to read the words.

Comment: This is probably a good compromise right now @sumelic.

Comment: Edited and expanded my answer using Google Ngrams to address your clarifying edit, please see @Lalit Jindal: and congratulations for asking a very interesting question here on English.SE!

Comment: @EnglishStudent Interesting but maybe I still wasn't clear before. What I'm saying is that when they use "atheist scientist" it means he is a scientist and an atheist.  

I was wrong. "Atheistic scientist" is used a lot but now when I look it up it always means atheism is part and parcel of the said scientist. In other words, atheism is the critical factor in what we are saying about the scientist. Maybe that's the difference when it comes to the general use of the words.

Comment: That's an interesting tool though. Ngram

Comment: Yes indeed Ngrams helps us trace these patterns *objectively* (as opposed to what we *think* is a pattern) @Lalit Jindal -- and when either form is used as in "atheist(ic) scientist" it's very unlikely that the scientist just *happens to be* atheist. Adjectives are almost always considered significant descriptors in modern usage. If we actually want to describe a scientist who just happens to be atheist, we are much more likely to say "he is a scientist, and atheist" or "that scientist is an atheist" thus avoiding tightly binding "atheist" & "scientist" when they are only loosely related here.

Answer (score -2):

Atheist is a noun (person/place/thing). In atheistic channel, channel is being modified. The general rule is if it's a person use atheist, if it's something else use atheistic.
e.g., Dawkins is one of the atheistic scientists.
XYZ is a pretty good atheist youtuber.
Communist regimes are usually atheist.
Hope this helps

Comment: “Atheist” can be a noun or an adjective. If we use “atheist” for people and “atheistic” elsewhere, why do you recommend saying “atheistic scientists” and “Communist regimes are usually atheist”?